# Set Page content to Elementor Template using wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to use wp_insert_post to create a page and set its content to an Elementor page and have the content be an Elementor template. Would I pass this into the 'post_content' parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* you can use below code to add content when page create */
$new_page = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_title' => 'hello',
            'post_content' => 'hello page content',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
        );
$new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
```

Comment: So do you put the Elementir json code in page_content?